# How to avoid leaking the existence of local API in Apache httpd?

Tags: configuration, http, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm building an API which will only be accessible to local services by using `Require local` in the `<Location>` directive. How can I make this return a 404 rather than 403 status code when accessed from a remote address? That way I can hide the fact that there is a service at the requested location.

I'd rather preserve the semantics of `Require local` than use `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [this isn't too difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15088830):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /unauthorized_remote_access
Redirect 404 /unauthorized_remote_access
```